# What is air pressure and is it the same as atmospheric pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, terminology, definition, atmospheric-science

What is air pressure and in particular is it the same as atmospheric pressure? Can the terms be used interchangeably, and why are there different instruments to measure the two properties?

Comment: What do you mean by air pressure?

Comment: Atmospheric pressure and air pressure are synonyms.

Answer (score -1):

Air pressure is the pressure of any amount of gas. It may be the pressure of He gas in a closed vessel and it can be calculated through the formula *Pv=nRt*.

However, Atmospheric pressure is the air pressure due to the weight of air column of atmosphere above you. It is typically equal to *1.01325 Pa* or *760mmofHg* or *1atm*.

Hence, we can say Air Pressure is a more generalised term and in day to day life the two can be used interchangabely.

Also, Pressure gauge can measure something as basic as the air pressure in a container whereas Barometer is typically meant for the measurement of Atmospheric Pressure.

Comment: This is not correct.  When air is referred to, it is always the mixture of gases in the atmosphere.

Comment: I am not denying of that fact. But what if I ask you to find the air pressure inside a closed jar? Will you say that it is the same as the atmospheric pressure? No right? That is what I am trying to explain.